# Show algebraically that the minima of $f(x)=4\sin(2x)\cos(2x)+2$ are achived on the x-axis.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=2\sin(4x)+2$

$f'(x)=8\cos(4x)$

$8\cos(4x)=0 \Rightarrow \cos(4x)=0$

$(4x)= \frac{\pi }{2}+n\pi$

$x=\frac{\pi }{8}+\frac{n\pi}{4} ,\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$

for each (2n) f(x) has a max value and for each (2n+1)

So how to show this fact algebraically, because by evaluation:

$f(\frac{\pi }{8})\neq 0$

Comment: $$\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A$$

Comment: Do you know a trigonometric identity involving $2\,\sin k\,\cos k$?

Comment: Prefix trigonometric functions' names with a backslash. That will make them LaTeX symbols, rendered in upright font and looking like function names (`\sin` → $\sin$) instead of italic font, looking like a multiplication of variables (`sin` → $sin$ ($s\cdot i\cdot n$?)).

Comment: You want the minimum value.  Therefore, you want to add an odd integer multiple of $\pi/4$ to $\pi/8$.  Notice that $$f\left(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = f\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right) = 2\sin\left(4 \cdot \frac{3\pi}{8}\right) + 2 = 2\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) + 2 = 2(-1) + 2 = 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Forget calculus. Note that $f(x)=2(\sin(4x)+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $$f(x)=2\sin (4x)+2$$

Know that the $\sin x$ is bounded by $-1$ & $1$.

So, does

$$-1 \leq \sin (4x) \leq 1$$

Follows by

$$-2 \leq 2\sin (4x) \leq 2$$

For minimum to occur we must have the least value. That is $-2$

Then, $f(x)=-2+2$

$$f(x)=0$$

You will have the root of the equation.

$$0=2\sin (4x)+2$$$

$$2\sin(4x)=-2$$

$$\sin (4x)=-1$$

Know that for sin x we have $-1$ at $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

$$4x=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2n\pi$$

$$x=\frac{3\pi}{8}+\frac{n\pi}{2}$$

Visual aid

[image]

Notice that the main function is only $\sin x$ Either a function achieve maxima or minima at $x=a$, they will not depend on the constant 2 which is the vertical shift.

Answer (score 0):

Your derivative expression can be rewritten as $$ 8\cos^2 2x - 8\sin^2 2x = 8 (\cos^2 2x - \sin^2 2x) = 8 \cos4x $$
using the well-known formula $\cos 2x = \cos^2 2x - \sin^2 2x$. Thus, the equation $ 8\cos^2 2x - 8\sin^2 2x = 0$ has the same solution as $8 \cos4x = 0$ which can be further simplified as $ \cos4x = 0$. The last equation can be swiftly computed using substitution $t = 4x$. Therefore, there is infinitely many solutions of your derivative expression and they can be written in the form $x = \frac{\pi}{8} + k \frac{\pi}{4} , \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Note: If you do not know how to deal with the equation $\cos 4x = 0$ via substitution $t = 4x$: solve $\cos t = 0$ which gives some solution for $t$ and then just divide this solution by $4$.